# ITextSharp export HTML to PDF with bottom-border

Tags: itext

I am trying to export the following HTML into a PDF with ITextSharp but the border does not show no matter how many ways I try.

The HTML shows the bottom border but once exported into the PDF it is lost in translation. Any ideas or ways that I can fake the bottom border?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<Table >
    <tr>
        <td class="test123">Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>    

</Table>
```

C#:

```
  string htmWrite = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Sample/Test.html"));
    Document document = new Document();
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadStyle("test123", HtmlTags.HR, "1");

css.LoadStyle("test123", "border-bottom-style", "solid");
css.LoadStyle("test123", "border-bottom-width", "2px");

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\test\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw =
             new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.SetStyleSheet(css);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmWrite));
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use XMLWorkerHelper.
The borders should set properly as you need in your HTML file. XMLWorkerHelper automatically takes care of applying that styles. For bottom border use as below:

```
border-bottom-color: Black;
border-bottom-width : 1px;
border-bottom-style : solid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround to use    XMLWorkerHelper

```
   Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\test\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();

        TextReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Sample/Test.html"));
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, r);document.Close();
```